# PHP / SOAP Get values of array in stdClass

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to get certain values which I call from a SOAP API in PHP.
But now I am stuck ... I don't know how to grab the values of `"EMAIL"` and `"FIRSTNAME"` as the index is not called `EMAI`L or `FIRSTNAME`.

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#406 (2) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(5) "EMAIL"
    ["value"]=>
    string(18) "mail@domain.tld"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#407 (2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(9) "FIRSTNAME"
        ["value"]=>
        string(5) "John"
      }
    }
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Ouh thanks, i guess that i got a decent hook in my brain... sorry for opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already can see which indices/properties to point to, just access them:

```
echo $data[0]->value; // email
echo $data[1]->value; // firstname
```

But for whatever reason, you need to check the corresponding `key` property first, you could use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($data as $o) {
    if($o->key === 'EMAIL' || $o->key === 'FIRSTNAME') {
        echo $o->value;
    }
}
```